# How to pluck hstore key with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, hstore

I have table with hstore column named `name_translations` with lots of translations:

```
{ 'en' => 'En name', 'es' => 'Es name', ... }
```

Its also serialized in model `store_accessor :name_translations`

I need to get `id` and `ru` key in name_translations hstore. I tried `Model.select("id, name_translations -> 'ru'")` and here is a query AR generates `Model Load (0.6ms)  SELECT id, name_translations -> 'ru' FROM "models"` but output has only ids:

```
[#<Model id: 95>,
 #<Model id: 101>,
...
```

Currently I stopped on a bit ugly code:

```
Model.pluck(:id, :name_translations).map { |id, name| [id, name['ru']] }
```

Whats a way to make it better?

Comment: What you have currently is better IMO.

Comment: @Зелёный Well your example works but why I dont see `something` in AR output? Its still only ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as` in the `select` query, for example:

```
=> result = Model.select("id, name_translations -> 'ru' as something")
=> result.first.something
```

> but output has only ids:
>
> `[#<Model id: 95>, #<Model id: 101>, ...`

This is how AR works, if you're using dynamic attributes it's never showed in the output because it's not a real column it's an *alias*.

Comment: I stopped on version with pluck `Model.pluck("id, name_translations -> 'ru' as something")`
Thanks!